# How to store element id accessed from jquery to a variable of Angular 2 Typescript

Tags: jquery, angular

I want to store the result from `jQuery(this).closest('li').attr('id')` this query to a variable of Angular 2 Typescript.

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {


 angVariable: any;
ngOnInit() {
    jQuery(this.elRef.nativeElement).on("click", "li a", function() {




/*  I want to store this query result to Angular typescript
variable say angVariable and query is   
"jQuery(this).closest('li').attr('id');"
basically I want to store Id of clicked li a into 
angular 2 typescript variable angVariable 

*/


});
    }
somefunction() { // I will use angVariable here 
}

}
```

enter code here

How can I do that?

Comment: Is there any way so that I can set typescript variable to true or false based on condition satisfy in jquery .

Answer (score 0):

You can store it as if it's a javascript variable, not?:

```
this.angVAriable = jQuery(this).closest('li').attr('id');
```

(before the class you should declare the variable `public angVariable;`)

Comment: Where do you use it? In typescript or attached js file?

Comment: export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{

angVariable : any;

ngOnInit() {
    jQuery(this.elRef.nativeElement).on("click", "li a"
        ,
        function() {
      
          // I want to store this query result to Angular typescript variable say angVariable and query is "jQuery(this).closest('li').attr('id');"
//basically I want to store Id of clicked li a into angular 2 typescript variable angVariable
      
        }
    );
  

}

somefunction(){
// I will use angVariable here 
}

}

Comment: Yes , I am using in typescript only

Comment: why do you use jQuery, you can handle it with _(click)_ too, but it would be easier if you make a plunker for it.

Comment: Actually "li a " is created dynamically , so I know how get id for dynamic that's why I used jquery to access id of clicked "li a " but I don't know how to store that id in anulgar id .

If you know how to get id in angular 2 typescript without writing (click) function in html because that "li a" is generated dynamically using json .

Answer (score 0):

```
  jQuery(this.elRef.nativeElement).find("#jstree").on("click", "li a"
            ,
            (event) => {

                let target = event.currentTarget;
                let idAttr = target.attributes.id;
                let id = idAttr.nodeValue;
                this.clickedId = id;
                this.clickedId = this.clickedId.replace("_anchor", "");
                //console.log(this.clickedId);
                console.log(this.clickedId);


            }
        );
```